# Why request.getParameter("") return null using jquery formdata

Tags: java, spring, servlets, request

When I try to retrieve my `verifyCodeActual` parameter on the server, the result is `null`.

```
String code = request.getParameter("verifyCodeActual"); // This is null
```

But I'm posting this parameter in the body as you can see in the chrome console data :

[the chrome console (data form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6KXe.png)

Here is the relevant part of the server-side java code:

[Relevant part of the server-side java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0tFJ.png)

Here is the JS ajax query:

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    var verifyCodeActual = $('#j_captcha').val();

    formData.append("verifyCodeActual", verifyCodeActual);

    $.ajax({
        url : (isEdit ? editShopUrl : registerShopUrl),
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: if my description does not clear,please tell me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add the relevant part of your Java code? Instead of tyhe image.

Comment: I've not done a great deal with using a FormData object but if what I read is correct, isn't the JSON structure being received by the server more like  **{"form": { "verifyCodeActual":"somevalue"}, "args":{}, etc}**  meaning that you need to first fetch the **form** value then get the **verifyCodeActual** from that?

Comment: it is my first time to use formData,i don't know how to get the form value or property

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has something to do with your java code which doesn't even look like a servlet. You have no doPost method there. What IDE are you using?

Here's what your servlet should look like:

```
@WebServlet("/modifyShop")
public class ModifyShop extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ModifyShop() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

        String code = request.getParameter("verifyCodeActual");
        System.out.println(code);

    }

}
```

Also since you are using Jquery, you can create ajax methods with Jquery which are generally simpler. There are many different ways you can send ajax requests with Jquery and i highly recommend checking out BalusC's answer here about [how to use Servlets and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax).

Here's an example where you can manually do it:

```
var verifyCodeActual = $('#j_captcha').val();
var params = {
    verifyCodeActual: verifyCodeActual
};

$.post("modifyShop", $.param(params), function(response) {
   //handle response here if you have any
});
```

Comment: thank for your answer，i will try to modify my js code. My IDE is intellij IDEA and i use spring instead of servlet

Comment: ah that would explain why your servlet doesn't look like a normal servlet.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

### Client

```
$.ajax({
    url : (isEdit ? editShopUrl : registerShopUrl),
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
        verifyCodeActual : $('#j_captcha').val()
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success ...
    }
});
```

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/modifyshop", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> modifyShop(@RequestBody Object verifyCodeActual) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(verifyCodeActual);
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, it happened HTTP status 415 after i change code

Comment: can you add  dataType: 'json' in ajax and then try it again